# Spring MVC: Can I point JSTL Import tag URL at an endpoint relative to current controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets, jstl

I am developing a couple of JSPs that inherit similar behaviour.  I am trying to achieve this by having a base controller and jsp that provides the basic behaviour and use the `<c:import />` tag to hit an endpoint defined in the sub-class of the base controller to get more content.  I am having an issue defining the url for the import tag to hit the correct endpoint from the sub-class controller.

The base controller:

```
@Controller
public abstract class AbstractController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/main")
    public String getForm() {
        return "MyForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/customForm")
    public abstract String getCustomForm();
}
```

MyForm.jsp

```
<c:import url="/customForm" />
```

My implementation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myController")
public class MyController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    public String getCustomForm() {
        return "MyCustomForm";
    }

}
```

Another implementation may look like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myController2")
public class MyController2 extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    public String getCustomForm() {
        return "MyCustomForm2";
    }

}
```

In this example it would not work, as the URL for the import references `/customForm`, but it needs to reference either `/myController/customForm` or `/myController2/customForm` depending on which controller was accessed to give the initial page (`/myController/main` or `/myController2/main`).

Is there any way I can achieve this behaviour using the standard `<c:import />` tag?

I thought about getting the request path in the `/main` endpoint and extracting the controller's mapping then adding it as a model attribute that I could then access on the jsp to build up the URL, but I feel there must be a better approach to doing this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you mind adding more context to what your are trying to achieve here

> I am developing a couple of JSPs that inherit similar behaviour. like?

Are you open for a different approach?

Comment: Basically my application will have a large number of forms, all of which will contain the same basic information, e.g. a name and description field plus more specific fields. When I submit the form the behaviour will all be the same, so I want to encapsulate this in one controller such that a dev can add a new form by simply extending the controller and returning their own section of the form.  The main form will contain the logic for bundling the form content and posting it to an endpoint, which the parent controller will handle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply achieve what you are looking for with [18.3 Tiles as explained here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html)

Your configurations will look like the following
    //baseform.jsp notice the tiles placeholders

```
 <form:form id="add_update_form" modelAttribute="mymodel" action="${ctx}/views/sections/action" method="post">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />

         <tiles:insertAttribute name="content" />

        <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />

    </form:form>
```

Your Tiles definition will look like

```
//tiles-layout.xml notice the contents of the placeholders defined above

<tiles-definitions>
    <!-- Abstract root definition -->
     <definition name="baseFrom" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/base/tiles/base.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/base/tiles/formheader.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="content" value=""/>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/base/tiles/formfooter.jsp"/>
    </definition>

     <definition name="main" extends="baseFrom">
         <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/sections/main.jsp"/>
    </definition> 
     <definition name="section1" extends="baseFrom">
         <put-attribute name="group" cascade="true" value="Terms"/>
         <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/sections/section1Form.jsp"/>
    </definition>

    <definition name="section2" extends="baseFrom">
         <put-attribute name="group" cascade="true" value="Terms"/>
         <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/sections/section2Form.jsp"/>
    </definition>

    <definition name="section3" extends="baseFrom">
         <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/sections/section2Form.jsp"/>
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

and Your controllers will look like

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/main")
    public String getForm() {
        return "main";//tiles definition
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/customForm1")
    public  String getCustomForm(){
     return "section1"; // tiles definition
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/customForm2")
    public  String getCustomForm(){
     return "section2";
    }
}
```

Now your developers will not have a need to extend the controller,  they will only have to add  a new tile definition, extend the baseForm definition and provider the new section jsp

```
in //tiles-layout.xml,&  put contents of the placeholder

    <definition name="newSection" extends="baseFrom">
             <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/sections/newSectionForm.jsp"/>
        </definition>
```

Comment: How about when I post the data from the JSP back to the controller, I will essentially be posting back a JSON object containing the fields that are on the custom form, so my endpoint that handles the post will have to figure out what to do with the varying data that comes back in the JSON.  The way I was doing it used generics in the parent controller such that the post endpoint would take `<? extends BaseForm>` and the subclass would define the concrete ? implementation. Then the framework would automatically instantiate the correct implementation from the JSON and I could just call save.

Comment: The approach suggested above, is just a one form, with lots of sections, i.e same modelAttribute across the board.Mainform could have a modelAttribute A with 2 fields, Section1 will have a modelAttribute that extends A with section specific fields, Section2 modelAttribute will also extend A with section specific fields, etc. Now when submitting to Controller your Json will have A fields plus a section specific fields, you can use some A`s fields to get a fresh copy of domain model  from DB, assuming that other sections were updated, and update domain with current section`s data and save it

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your question, you can capture the controller mapping as a path variable and resolve your view based on that. For example, add the  following mapping in your *AbstractController*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{controller}/customForm")
public String getCustomForm(@PathVariable String controller) {
    String returnValue = null;
    if (controller.equals("myController")) {
        returnValue = "MyCustomForm";
    } else if (controller.equals("MyCustomForm2")) {
        returnValue = "MyCustomForm2";
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```